# How to find the number of rows in a DataGridView where the values in a column are within a specified range?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

One column of my DataGridView contains a number of different values.

For example:

```
columnName
10
21
23
25
12
14
16
28
30
29
36
47
56
65
78
89
96
121
126
21
132
55
16
... etc
```

Here I need to separate the values which lies between the range 0-30, 30-60, 60-90.

```
var sector1 = "no.of values lies between 0-30";
var sector2 = "no.of values lies between 30-60";
var sector3 = "no.of values lies between 60-90";
var sector4 = "no.of values lies between 90-120";
```

Can any one suggest the syntax to find the count of rows between two ranges?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
var values = datagridview.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(x => (int)x.Cells[column].Value);

var sector1 = values.Count(x => x >= 0 && x < 30);
[...]
```

Comment: i tried this,'try
     {
     var values = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => (int)x.Cells[columnName].Value);
     var sector1 = values.Count(x => x >= 0 && x < 30);
     var sector2 = values.Count(x => x >= 30 && x < 60);
     var sector3 = values.Count(x => x >= 60 && x < 90);
     var sector4 = values.Count(x => x >= 90 && x < 120);
     [...]
     MessageBox.Show(sector1.ToString());
     [...]
     }
     catch
     {
      MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
     }'.... but i'm getting error message only